# laravel mass assignment on set attribute and except column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There is a "full_name" column in my database, but there are no "first_name" and "last_name" columns in my database.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
</form>
```

This is my model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name'];

    public function setFullNameAttribute()
    {
        $this->attributes['full_name'] = $this->attributes['first_name'].' '.$this->attributes['last_name'];
    }
}
```

This is code in my controller Class

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->update($validated);
}
```

---

After I submit form, there is an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'
```

I know what Cause this, is because `$guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name']`

But if I didn't guarded those fields, there is an error:

```
"Undefined index: first_name"
```

I know what cause this, is because there is no "first_name" column in my database.

---

> So I get stuck and don't know how to update "full_name" into database,
>   and prevent assign "first_name" and "last_name" fields.

PS, I don't use `$user->save()` is because there are mass assignment need to update in real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the controller role to adapt the inputs to your models/repositories.

your model should reflect the datable only:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['full_name'];
}
```

Your controller

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (isset($validated['first_name']) && isset($validated['last_name'])) {
        $validated['full_name'] = $validated['first_name'].' '.$validated['last_name'];
    }
    unset($validated['first_name'], $validated['last_name']);
    $user->update($validated);
}
```

but if you want to keep using your method, i suggest you overcharge the update method

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name'];

    /**
    * @param array $attributes
    * @param array $options
    * @return bool
    */
    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
    {
        if (isset($attributes['first_name']) && isset($attributes['last_name'])) {
            $attributes['full_name'] = $attributes['first_name'].' '.$attributes['last_name'];
        }
        unset($attributes['first_name'], $attributes['last_name']);
        return parent::update($attributes, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of overwrite update method is good, which means I can use it everywhere, as long as there are 'first_name' and 'last_name', the model will automatically generate 'full_name' and insert into database!

Comment: But if protected $guarded = ['full_name']; then it won't insert 'full_name' into database.

Comment: Maybe change it to protected $fillable = ['full_name']; or keep using protected $guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name']; 
 
Could you change the code? So I may choose you as the best answer:)

Comment: @Autodesk take in count that `$guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name'];` and `$fillable = ['full_name'];` are not the same thing. Updated the answer, but you should really use the first solution. or you will end up with a lot of exceptions in your code.

Comment: I like the first solution but it won't work: protected $guarded = ['full_name']; It's clean and clear, but it won't update the full_name column, because it's guarded :(

Comment: You're right that $guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name']; not reflect the datatable and end up with a lot of exceptions in my code, and they have been 'unset' in the custom update method, sorry my foolish to asking you to change the answer :P

Comment: Well,... so there is left with only one option is $fillable = ['full_name']; so maybe $fillable = ['full_name']; is the only way I can do?

Comment: @Autodesk you know that $guarded doesn't prevent you from assigning the `full_name` attribute like you are doing. it only prevents it's mass assignment. for example `User::create(['full_name' => 'hi there'])` or `new User(['full_name' => 'hi there'])`. so it's save to use it as you do with the `save()` method

Comment: $guarded only effect on mass assignment, and `update()` is mass asignment, so `update()` won't update those $guarded fields , but `save()` will update $guarded fields, because `save()` is not mass asignment. Am I correct?

Comment: absolutely correct, forgot you are using `update()` and not `save()`

Comment: Yeah I'm using `update()`. Thank you very much teaching me so many things :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is :

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['full_name'];

}
```

Store function looks like this:

```
public function store(StoreUser $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $validated['full_name'] = $validated['first_name'].' '. $validated['last_name'];
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->update($validated);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but if it needs to be changed in the future, which means I have to modify it on every class :(

Comment: `protected $guarded = ['first_name', 'last_name'];` doesn't serve anything in your example.